# Change in @JsonAny(S|G}etter from 1.7.4 to 1.9.3?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have code that basically does the following to read in properties that are added to json like e.g. 'name' and ' value' in the follow JSON `{"operation":"write-attribute","address":[{"subsystem":"web"},{"connector":"http"}],"name":"socket-binding","value":"jndi"}`.
As the methods are generic, I can's just rely on hardcoding name and value - other json strings could contain other properties that should be "caught".

```
@JsonAnySetter
public void addAdditionalProperty(String key, Object value) {
    if (additionalProperties == null)
        additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    additionalProperties.put(key,value);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void setAdditionalProperties(Map<String, Object> additionalProperties) {
    this.additionalProperties = additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String,Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonIgnore
public String getName() {
   return (String) getProperty("name");
}

@JsonIgnore
public String getValue() {
   return (String) getProperty("value");
}
```

This code works well with Jackson 1.7.4, but fails in 1.9.3 where the additionalProperties are not set.
I fail to see if this is an intended change or if its is a regression.

If it is an intended change - does anyone know how to "fix" my code to work again?

Full code [is here](http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/?p=rhq/rhq.git;a=blob;f=modules/plugins/jboss-as-7/src/main/java/org/rhq/modules/plugins/jbossas7/json/Operation.java;h=23df1a5d4780fba577c7aaae84a3bc5d5df34af3;hb=14b81e5036bbbc47bb09fac2dc86b7166b1846fd) , test [is here](http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/?p=rhq/rhq.git;a=blob;f=modules/plugins/jboss-as-7/src/test/java/org/rhq/modules/plugins/jbossas7/OperationJsonTest.java;h=67f2243d23f38c362d7a8e612170f04d85d79c3e;hb=14b81e5036bbbc47bb09fac2dc86b7166b1846fd)  (first test, OperationSerDeserTest)

Comment: As described: the whole additionalProperties are not set, while they were in 1.7.4.

Comment: Ah OK, I understood that there was a runtime error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like potential bug to me -- easiest way to figure out is to either send question to user list, or file a Jira. I can do latter, see if I can see what happens.

Comment: Looks like there's some sort of (internal) conflict between regular getters, any getter -- Jira issue is [https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-744], looks like a bug so far. Odd that unit tests did not catch this.